# React Native - Image from localhost URL not rendering

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display my uploaded image saved from to my backend folder. Its on different file so to retrieve I have to call it http://localhost:3333/files/56337191_1672525486183139_5858638560600522752_n-1574093787215.png. But it does not work on my react native code, I tested it on android and IOS.

```
<Image
  style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
  source={{uri: 'http://localhost:3333/files/56337191_1672525486183139_5858638560600522752_n-1574093787215.png'}}
/>
```

It works when I open it on browser.

Comment: If you are running this using an external device, you probably need to map localhost:3333 to your machine's port 3333. Try a command like > adb reverse tcp:3333 tcp:3333 if that's the case

Comment: That's right, I'm running on an external device, would running this command work?

Comment: running `adb reverse tcp:3333 tcp:3333` in a console should be sufficient if this is a port mapping problem. I can fill out a proper answer if that fixes it for you or if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

The localhost only runs on your computer, you need to map the server to run on your network locally or to deploy the backend somewhere. I have an easy solution for you

Check out ngrok.com
And you can use that to create a secure connection from localhost to a temporary server that is forwarding traffic from a specified port on localhost

Open new terminal when server is running and
    npm i ngrok -g
    ngrok http 3333

Easy and configure the react native app to point to the url they gave you instead of localhost:3333

Answer (score -1):

Are you testing with an external device or a simulated device on you computer?

Comment: Exactly, I am using an external device. More precisely Expo on Android.